# ANDROID: SPLASH: Why I always see splash screen when app is resumed

Tags: android

I just created my first proper android app and ran into the splash screen issue. Whenever my app comes into foreground, splash screen is displayed first and then the last opened activity is shown. 
The resume feature looks fine but why the splash screen is always showed. In other apps, I don't see such behavior.
Here is my code:

```
minSdkVersion 24
targetSdkVersion 26
```

I used **android:noHistory="true"** but still no changes
I tried **intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);** but still no change

**From AndroidManifesh.xml**

```
<activity
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".activities.SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity" />
```

**From SplashActivity.java**

```
Handler handler;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }, Constant.SPLASH_SCREEN_TIMEOUT);
}
```

What am I missing?
Any more code is required for explanation?

Comment: Please share you MainActivity code also, maybe some thing is wrong in yourMainActivity

Comment: If this is happening when navigating back from `RegistrationPhoneNumberActivity` to `SplashActivity` by clicking back button, you should override `onBackPressed()` in `RegistrationPhoneNumberActivity` and then call `finish()` inside it.

Comment: @MohammedFarhan edited code

Comment: This is happening on all activities. I am on a screen, press the home button on phone. Now, whether I resume the app or click the icon to open it, I always see the splash screen. I can see app is running in the background.

Comment: this is happening because you must be calling finish() in onBackPressed in your activities , do call finish() in activities

Comment: remove this   android:noHistory="true" firstly then run code

Comment: I didn't see `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` how you could run the app without this ? You must be getting **android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity did not call through to super.onCreate()**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this `android:noHistory="true"` from all the activities.

A value of `"true"` means that the activity will not leave a historical trace. It will not remain in the activity stack for the task, so the user will not be able to return to it

Comment: Perfect, removing noHistory did the tick, thanks a lot

Comment: i am glad it worked for you , Happy coding :), ask me anything if you want anytime