# (Android) Always display Splash Screen when change module on Xamarin Forms 3.3?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, splash-screen

I have problem when use `Xamarin Forms` version 3.3.
On Android, when switch module (Example module `Home`), `Splash Screen` always display ( I encounter this problem between each screen on Android). (On iOS, It works perfect)

[image: switch module]

[image: Splash Screen]

On `Xamarin Forms` version 2.5, It has not this problem.

How to prevent display `Splash Screen` when switch module on Xamarin Forms 3.3.

I tried it, but It does not work.
[ANDROID: SPLASH: Why I always see splash screen when app is resumed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51998859/android-splash-why-i-always-see-splash-screen-when-app-is-resumed)

This is my code:

```xml
<style name="MyProject" parent="MyProject.Base">
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
   <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
   <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/noPaddingButtonStyle</item>
   <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/noPaddingEditTextStyle</item>
 </style>
```

And use it at `MainActivity.cs`:

```cs
[Activity(Label = "MyProject",
    Theme = "@style/MyProject",
    Icon = "@drawable/ic_launcher",
    LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleInstance,
    Name = "com.myproject.mobile.MainActivity",
    MainLauncher = true,
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation,
    WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustPan)]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Show me your MasterDetailPage code may be then we cam pin point this

Comment: I try upgrade to X.F 3.3 to X.F 3.4 and It's work perfect and speed faster than X.F3.3.

Answer (score 0):

You encounter this problem between each screen on Android ? or only when you switch of application on your smartphone (and come back to your app) ?

If the problem is the second : be sure you have `MainLauncher = true` before your splashscreen activity declaration.

Example:

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class SplashScreenActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is the frist, I encounter this problem between each screen on Android.